# File gets automaticaly deleted after uploading

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

File gets automaticaly deleted after uploading to the server, also sometimes it gets edited. Already reset our shared hosting account, created new cpanel even formatted our machine also. But same problem still exists.

Comment: Is there anything in the PHP error logs? Does turning WP_DEBUG on create any logs? When you say the file sometimes gets edited, what exactly has changed? (That's really odd.) Are the filesystem permissions set correctly for the uploads folder? Are there any automatic backup / restore jobs in your setup? If you disable all the plugins and choose a default theme does it still go wrong? And if you're really stuck you probably need to talk to your host for help, not us, sorry.

Comment: Sometime its deleted the plugin file. Sometime its deleted the style.css file. There is nothing on error log except the plugin related error because of deleted file.

Comment: Oh, you're having trouble uploading a plugin or theme? You didn't say that. Are you doing this through WordPress, or manually e.g. via shell or FTP access?

Comment: We dont have any issue on uploading plugin or theme.After upload the plugin file is deleted with in 5 min of interval .We are Uploading via cpanel File manager.

Comment: OK. I think is definitely one for your hosting's support then. It shouldn't do that.